# Demonstrate that $\angle AKB+\angle AFB+\angle ACB=\frac{\pi }{2}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the right triangle $ABC$, the leg $AC$ is three times larger than $AB$. $AC$ is divided by the $K$ and $F$ points into three equal parts. Demonstrate that$$\angle AKB+\angle AFB+\angle ACB=\frac{\pi }{2}$$

Attempt: Let $\angle AKB = \alpha$, $\angle AFB = \beta$ and $ \angle ACB = \lambda$. We have $\alpha = \frac\pi 4$, and since $\tan \beta = \frac{1}{2}$, $\tan{\lambda}=\frac{1}{3}$ we write: $$\tan(\beta + \lambda)= 1$$ can anybody help me? With a solution by trigonometric equation, or a different approach than I did

Comment: You can try evaluating $\tan{(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)}$ using the formula, which yields denominator$=0$, making the value of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ obvious.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456746/show-that-arctan-frac12-arctan-frac13-frac-pi4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a $3 \times 2$ table.

We need to calculate the value of $a+b+c$.

After some angle chasing shown in the image, we get $b+c=45$.

(Note that angle $A_5 A_4 A_{11}$ is $45$ since triangle $A_5 A_4 A_{11}$ is a
right isosceles triangle.)

Since $a=45$, $a+b+c=90$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another similar, popular approach:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution by trigonometry.

We need to prove that $$45^{\circ}+\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}=90^{\circ}$$ or
$$\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}=45^{\circ}$$ or
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}=1,$$ which is true.